# Spring Kafka: Multiple Listeners for different objects within an ApplicationContext

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Can I please check with the community what is the best way to listen to multiple topics, with each topic containing a message of a different class?

I've been playing around with Spring Kafka for the past couple of days. My thought process so far:

- Because you need to pass your deserializer into DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory when initializing a KafkaListenerContainerFactory. This seems to indicate that if I need multiple containers each deserializing a message of a different type, I will not be able to use the @EnableKafka and @KafkaListener annotations.
- This leads me to think that the only way to do so would be to instantiate multiple KafkaMessageListenerContainers.
- And given that KafkaMessageListenerContainers is single threaded and I need to listen to multiple topics at the same time, I really should be using multiple ConcurrentKafkaMessageListenerContainers.

Would I be on the right track here? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Same question is asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43142295/problems-adding-multiple-kafkalistenercontainerfactories/52441951

Answer (score 15):

Here is a very simple example.

```
// -----------------------------------------------
// Sender
// -----------------------------------------------

@Configuration
public class SenderConfig {
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        ......
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Class1> producerFactory1() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, Class1>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Class1> kafkaTemplate1() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory1());
    }

    @Bean
    public Sender1 sender1() {
        return new Sender1();
    }

    //-------- send the second class --------

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Class2> producerFactory2() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, Class2>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Class2> kafkaTemplate2() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory2());
    }

    @Bean
    public Sender2 sender2() {
        return new Sender2();
    }
}

public class Sender1 {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, Class1> kafkaTemplate1;

    public void send(String topic, Class1 c1) {
        kafkaTemplate1.send(topic, c1);
   }
}

public class Sender2 {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, Class2> kafkaTemplate2;

    public void send(String topic, Class2 c2) {
        kafkaTemplate2.send(topic, c2);
    }
}

// -----------------------------------------------
// Receiver
// -----------------------------------------------

@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class ReceiverConfig {

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        ......
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Class1> consumerFactory1() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),
            new JsonDeserializer<>(Class1.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Class1> kafkaListenerContainerFactory1() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Class1> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory1());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Receiver1 receiver1() {
        return new Receiver1();
    }

    //-------- add the second listener

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Class2> consumerFactory2() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),
            new JsonDeserializer<>(Class2.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Class2> kafkaListenerContainerFactory2() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Class2> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory2());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Receiver2 receiver2() {
        return new Receiver2();
    }
}

public class Receiver1 {
    @KafkaListener(id="listener1", topics = "topic1", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory1")
    public void receive(Class1 c1) {
        LOGGER.info("Received c1");
    }
}

public class Receiver2 {
    @KafkaListener(id="listener2", topics = "topic2", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory2")
    public void receive(Class2 c2) {
        LOGGER.info("Received c2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which means that if we wish to add another topic and corresponding listener for it, we'll have to write code for it. Every time. Is that assumption correct ?

Comment: a little explanation would have helped along with only code that you have shared

Answer (score 9):

You can use the annotations, you would just need to use a different listener container factory for each.

The framework will create a listener container for each annotation.

You can also listen to multiple topics on a single-threaded container but they would be processed, er, on a single thread.

Take a look at the [code from my SpringOne Platform talk last year](https://github.com/SpringOnePlatform2016/grussell-spring-kafka) - you might want to look at app6, which shows how to use a `MessageConverter` instead of a deserializer, which might help simplify your configuration.

Comment: Which means that if we wish to add another topic and corresponding listener for it, we'll have to write code for it. Every time. Is that assumption correct ?

Comment: Don't comment on answers to old questions; ask a new question to explain exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to use the code below to apply your sence

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class ConsumerConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${kafka.group-id}")
    private String groupId;

    /**
     * Configuration of Consumer properties.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    //@Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);

        return props;
    }

    //@Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, ClassA> consumerFactory1() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),
                new ClassA());
    }

    /**
     * Kafka Listener Container Factory.
     * @return
     */
    @Bean("kafkaListenerContainerFactory1")
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, ClassA>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory1() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ClassA> factory;
        factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory1());
        return factory;
    }

    //@Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, ClassB> consumerFactory2() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),
                new ClassB());
    }

    /**
     * Kafka Listener Container Factory.
     * @return
     */
    @Bean("kafkaListenerContainerFactory2")
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, ClassB>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory2() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ClassB> factory;
        factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory2());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ReceiverClass receiver() {
        return new ReceiverClass();
    }

    class ReceiverClass {
        @KafkaListener(topics = "topic1", group = "group-id-test",
                containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory1")
        public void receiveTopic1(ClassA a) {
            System.out.println("ReceiverClass.receive() ClassA : " + a);
        }

        @KafkaListener(topics = "topic2", group = "group-id-test",
                containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory2")
        public void receiveTopic2(ClassB b) {
            System.out.println("ReceiverClass.receive() Classb : " + b);
        }

    }

    class ClassB  implements Deserializer  {

        @Override
        public void configure(Map configs, boolean isKey) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public Object deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

    class ClassA  implements Deserializer {

        @Override
        public void configure(Map configs, boolean isKey) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public Object deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good amount of code! A bit of explanation of it, some decisions you made on it, how it works etc. would be helpful.

Comment: It work on my project. I just use UT to test it.
There is a note:
 I commented out `//@Bean` in two funcs: consumerFactory1, consumerFactory2. I don't know what is problem ?
Exception:
   NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: Now, I am busy with my projects. so you please watch this topic I soon create a example code to demonstration,

Comment: @caovn, did you manage to find the problem with bean definitions?